# Bind a windows machine to AD with one command line

Tags: command-line, active-directory, bind

when I bind a Windows PC to my Domain I use the following command line without any issue.

```
// Run as administrator
Add-Computer –DomainName mylab.org –Credential (Get-Credential)
```

After executing the above command line, a pop up windows comes asking me for an admin user name and password to authorize the bind to the AD.  I fill out the info and I restart the machine.  Everything ok.

Question, how can I modify the above command line and add my user and password and a reboot command so it does everything automatically?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can use djoin.exe program or JoinDomainOrWorkGroup() method of Win32_ComputerSystem class. If result of JoinDomainOrWorkGroup() = 0 then reboot using Win32Shutdown(6,0) method of Win32_OperatingSystem class.